# Converting boxplot to violin plot, error: discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, function, loops, ggplot2

I would like to convert the code I have written to make boxplots using ggplot2 to violin plots. The code is complicated because it is a loop, so I have been having a lot of trouble making minor adjustments to graphs and analyses. In this case, when I try to use similar code to create the violin plots using geom_violin, I get the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale."

I have read prior questions that mention adding as.numeric (ex. y=as.numeric(variable)) to convert the y variable to numeric, but this does not seem to be working in this situation. I also tried to add scale_x_discrete(), which does not work either.

ggboxplot code, which works as expected:

```
lapply(cytokine_names, function(s){
Tukey_data <- TukeyHSD(aov(as.formula(paste0(s, " ~ ICH_SAH")),
data = current_data))$ICH_SAH
maxvalues <- dat %>% group_by(ICH_SAH) %>% summarise(MAX = max(.data[[s]], na.rm = T))

pval <- as.data.frame(Tukey_data) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("Group") %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Start = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[1],
End = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[2]) %>%
left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("Start" = "ICH_SAH")) %>%
left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("End" = "ICH_SAH")) %>% ungroup() %>%
mutate(ypos = c(11,12,13)) %>% 
mutate(End = factor(End, levels = c("CTL","ICH","SAH"))) %>% 
rowwise() #%>%

pval$p_adj_num <- pval$`p adj`

i <- pval$`p adj` < 0.05
ii <- pval$`p adj` < 0.01
iii <- pval$`p adj` < 0.001
pval$`p adj` <- as.character(paste0("p = ",round(pval$`p adj`, 3)))
pval[i,]$`p adj` <- paste0(pval[i,]$`p adj`, "*")
pval[ii,]$`p adj` <- paste0(pval[ii,]$`p adj`, "**")
pval[iii,]$`p adj` <- "p < 0.001***"

print(pval)

ggboxplot(dat, x ="ICH_SAH" , y = s ,
fill = "ICH_SAH", palette = "grey",
>               ) +
geom_signif(data = pval, manual = TRUE,
aes(xmax = End, xmin = Start, y_position= ypos, annotations = (`p adj`))) +
ggtitle("CSF cytokine concentrations: Control vs ICH vs SAH") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.position = "right") + labs(fill = "Sample Type") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,14), breaks=seq(0,14,by=5)) 

> })
```

my attempt at ggplot and geom_violin to make a violin plot, which give me the above error:

```
lapply(cytokine_names, function(s){
Tukey_data <- TukeyHSD(aov(as.formula(paste0(s, " ~ ICH_SAH")),
data = current_data))$ICH_SAH
maxvalues <- dat %>% group_by(ICH_SAH) %>% summarise(MAX = max(.data[[s]], na.rm = T))

pval <- as.data.frame(Tukey_data) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("Group") %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Start = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[1],
End = unlist(strsplit(Group,"-"))[2]) %>%
left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("Start" = "ICH_SAH")) %>%
left_join(.,maxvalues, by = c("End" = "ICH_SAH")) %>% ungroup() %>%
mutate(ypos = c(11,12,13)) %>% 
mutate(End = factor(End, levels = c("CTL","ICH","SAH"))) %>% 
rowwise() #%>%

pval$p_adj_num <- pval$`p adj`

i <- pval$`p adj` < 0.05
ii <- pval$`p adj` < 0.01
iii <- pval$`p adj` < 0.001
pval$`p adj` <- as.character(paste0("p = ",round(pval$`p adj`, 3)))
pval[i,]$`p adj` <- paste0(pval[i,]$`p adj`, "*")
pval[ii,]$`p adj` <- paste0(pval[ii,]$`p adj`, "**")
pval[iii,]$`p adj` <- "p < 0.001***"

print(pval)

ggplot(dat, aes(x ="ICH_SAH" , y = s, fill = "ICH_SAH", palette = "grey")) + 
geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.position = "right") + labs(fill = "Sample Type") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,14), breaks=seq(0,14,by=5)) + 
geom_signif(data = pval, manual = TRUE,
aes(xmax = End, xmin = Start, y_position= ypos, annotations = (`p adj`))) + 
ggtitle("CSF cytokine concentrations: Control vs ICH vs SAH") 

> })
```

Comment: Try with `ggplot(dat, aes(x =ICH_SAH , y = .data[[s]], fill = ICH_SAH))`. For you boxplot you are using `ggpubr::ggboxplot`. In ggplot you have to use unquoted column names. Also to add your grey fill scale try `+ scale_fill_grey()`.

Comment: Is `dat$s` composed of a continuous variable (i.e. a number), or a discrete value?  The error message you are getting seems most likely a result of `scale_y_continuous(...)` being used to apply a scale function to whatever you mapped to y which is *not* continuous.

Comment: @stefan Thank you so much for pointing out that my boxplot was made using ggpubr, not ggplot2. I had spent so much time trying out different boxplot options that I had completely forgotten about that. I was able to create the violin plots using ggpubr instead so that I am able to keep pretty much the same code and it worked perfectly.